# Kivy refresh layout (Async Loading)

Tags: python, kivy

I have a ListView that where each item has a AsyncImage and a Label. While the images load it shows the layout with gaps between each item.

```
-------

Item

-------

Item 

-------
```

When the first interaction happens (a scroll occurs), the layout refreshes and the gaps disappear.

```
-------
Item    
-------  
Item 
-------
```

I'd really like to have the layout refresh when an image finishes loading. How do I refresh a layout?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually you can ask the widget to update it's canvas by calling [widget.canvas.ask_update()](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.graphics.instructions.html#kivy.graphics.instructions.Canvas.ask_update).

For a layout you could try triggering the layout of the widgets inside it by calling [layout_instance.do_layout()](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.layout.html#kivy.uix.layout.Layout.do_layout).