# Kivy: Label text does not update during for-loop

Tags: python, for-loop, label, kivy

I have an issue when I try to update a label text during a for-loop.  There are similar entries (e.g.: [Update properties of a kivy widget while running code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27213545/update-properties-of-a-kivy-widget-while-running-code)) but they do not seem to fit my issue exactly (or I missed the point…).
I run following code:

*.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
#from time import sleep

class MyBox(BoxLayout):
    tobeupd = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(MyBox,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.tobeupd = '#'

    def upd_ltxt(self):
        for i in range(1,10):
            self.tobeupd = str(i)
            print(self.tobeupd)
            input('Write something: ')  # new line, see edit below
            #sleep(0.5) 

class updApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyBox()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    updApp().run()
```

*.kv

```
<MyBox>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    cols: 2
    Label:
        text: root.tobeupd
    Button:
        text: 'Start Update'
        on_release: root.upd_ltxt()
```

Whereas the ‘print’ statement updates the shell regularly, the label text updates at the end of the for-loop only.
Can anyone explain to me why Kivy works this way and how I can overcome this problem?

EDIT: According to PM2Ring and Gugas, I changed the code in order to avoid the sleep-function. The problem remains if I ask the user to enter something before the loop can be continued. The values are updated in the shell but not on the label.

Comment: I don't know Kivy, but it's generally a Bad Idea to call `time.sleep` in GUI code because it blocks _everything_, so the GUI engine doesn't get a chance to update the layout. If you need delays you have to use the functions / methods that the GUI framework supplies for that purpose.

Comment: @PM2Ring is actually right, the system is probably going to change the label and after getting hit with a sleep it won't update, try it without the sleep statement and check the problem persists.

Comment: @PM2ring, Gugas: I edited the code, but the problem persists. Any idea?

Comment: The `input` function blocks while it's waiting for user input, so it has the same effect as calling `sleep`, and so Kivy still doesn't get a chance to update the layout. As I said earlier, I don't know Kivy, but I assume it has functions for forcing the layout to update. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21041145/4014959) may be relevant.

Comment: You never assign the result of `input` to anything, that I can tell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `threading` for this.
When you do a loop or wait for an input in kivy, the main thread is waiting, and nothing will update on the app. `threading` will prevent that.
Use `threading` to make another thread besides the main thread.
Example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
import threading

Builder.load_string('''

<MyBox>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    cols: 2
    Label:
        text: root.tobeupd
    Button:
        text: 'Start Update'
        on_release: root.upd_ltxt()

''')

class MyBox(BoxLayout):
    tobeupd = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(MyBox,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.tobeupd = '#'

    def upd_ltxt(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self.update_label).start()

    def update_label(self):
        for i in range(1,10):
            print(self.tobeupd)
            self.tobeupd = str(i)
            input('Write something: ')  # new line, see edit below



class updApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyBox()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    updApp().run()
```

Now its worth mentioning that you can keep pushing the button and start threads, even if the first did not finish yet. This might be an unwanted behavior.
This can be prevented by disabling the button in the beginning of the thread, and enabling it again at the end.

Give the button an id in kv:

```
Button:
    id: updatebutton
    text: 'Start Update'
    on_release: root.upd_ltxt()
```

And in the thread do like this:

```
def update_label(self):

    self.ids.updatebutton.disabled = True

    for i in range(1,10):
        self.tobeupd = str(i)
        input('Write something: ')

    self.ids.updatebutton.disabled = False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Kivys `clock` Class, which is an Event dispatcher. It will schedule an event, which is a function. For example, updating your labels text.

```
from kivy.clock import Clock   

def to_be_called_back(self,dt):
    print("This function should be periodically executed")

def do_the_loop(self):
    Clock.schedule_interval(self.to_be_called(),0.5)
```

Here the function `to_be_called()` will be called every 0.5 seconds. The `dt` variable stands for deltatime and is just apparently needed by the Clock class (without it, it made problems with my code)

I'd still put the `do_the_loop()` function into a separate thread. But thats what kivy provides for it. [If you want to know more about the clock Class head over here.](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/events.html)

Answer (score 0):

I believe all you need to do is put

```
root.update()
```

whenever you want the GUI to update, so therefore in the loop, after the text change has been made. Works in tkinter like a charm. You can also restrict the update to a specific text area by changing root (or main) to the name of the text area.

Comment: This is `Kivy` not `tkinter` They dont have same terminology.